# problems when configure omnet (omnetpp-5.4.1)

Tags: omnet++

I have run into probelms when configure omnetpp-5.1.1 on windows10

1. I have installed gcc sucessfully as showed below:

```
PS C:\Users\admin> gcc -v
 specs
COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
mingw32
../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
win32
gcc  6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
```

2.when I follow the instructions and Type "./configure"
the problem ouccurs: here is my log

```
/d/softwares/omnet/omnetpp/omnetpp-5.4.1$ ./configure
configure: loading site script /mingw64/etc/config.site
checking build system type... x86_64-w64-mingw32
checking host system type... x86_64-w64-mingw32
configure: -----------------------------------------------
configure: reading configure.user for your custom settings
configure: -----------------------------------------------
checking for clang... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for clang++... clang++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether clang++ accepts -g... yes
checking for clang++... clang++
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking whether clang++ supports -fno-stack-protector... yes
checking whether clang++ supports -Wl,--no-as-needed... yes
checking whether clang++ supports -Wl,--as-needed... yes
checking for swapcontext... no
checking if shared libs need -fPIC... no
checking for dlopen with CFLAGS="" LIBS=""... no
checking if --export-dynamic linker option is supported/needed... test failed
checking for flags needed to link with static libs containing simple modules... --whole-archive
configure: NOTE: Use the following syntax when linking with static libraries
configure: containing simple modules and other dynamically registered components:
configure:    clang++ ... -Wl,--whole-archive <libs> -Wl,--no-whole-archive ...
checking whether linker supports -rpath... yes
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for flex... flex
checking lex output file root... lex.yy
checking lex library... none needed
checking whether yytext is a pointer... no
checking for make... make
checking for perl... perl
checking for swig... not found
checking for math with CFLAGS="" LIBS=""... yes
**checking for standard C++ lib with CFLAGS="" LIBS="-lstdc++"... no
checking for standard C++ lib with CFLAGS="" LIBS="-lc++"... no
checking for standard C++ lib with CFLAGS="" LIBS="-lcxa"... no**
configure: error: Standard C++ library -lstdc++_s or -lstdc++ or -lcxx or -lcxa or -lc++ not found
# here is the probelm
```

*It always shows the probelms missing C++ lib, but I don't know if it's the broken lib's problem. If so, what should I do to fix this problem.
Please help me. Thanks a lot!*

Answer (score 1):

1. OMNeT++ for Windows does not require installing external GCC from MinGW. All necessary tools and libraries are already present in the ZIP package.
2. Make sure that real-time protection in your antivirus is turned off during calling `./configure` and `make`.